# Batch wildcards not accepted

Tags: batch-file

How do I do reshacker -extract on all files in the system32 folder as well as get their filename and add .rc to the end of each output file.

reshacker.exe does not accept wildcards so im not sure what to do.

I have tried the following:

ResHacker.exe -extract C:\windows\system32\*.*, C:\resources\%1.rc, dialog,,

it is supposed to extract dialog data from each file in system 32 and save this data as %the_filename%.rc.

Comment: Take a look at [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)...

Comment: the for loop will still need either a variable or wildcards and those dont work with reshackers command line syntax.

Comment: No, the for loop doesn't need wildcards. You can loop through filenames using wildcards, and each pass through the loop will call reshacker with a single filename. Again, take a look at for - type `for /?` at a command prompt.

Comment: got it working now thanks

Comment: You may want to share your solution as an answer (and even accept it)?

Comment: ill do it shortly